# Get the latest commit in a repository with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I want to get the last commit metadata (the youngest one by date) in a repository using JGit.

I know that I can get the commit metadata using:

```java
try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository))
{
    RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(repository.resolve(commitHash));
}
```

But how to get the latest commit hash?

Is there any other way to get the youngest by date `RevCommit` in a repository directly?

Comment: Can you clarify what _latest_ means exactly? Do you mean the youngest by date? From all branches?

Comment: Do you mean the commit that `HEAD` ultimately points to?

Comment: Yes Exactly, the yougest by date from all the branches. is it Important to look up for him for all the branches, because I thought that I can look up for him relatively to a repo regardless of the branches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare by dates of last commits in all branches.
`ListMode.ALL` can be changed to `ListMode.REMOTE` to compare only remote branches.
Or... the fluent setter `.setListMode(whatever)` can be omitted to read from the local repository.

```
RevCommit youngestCommit = null;
Git git = new Git(repository);
List<Ref> branches = git.branchList().setListMode(ListMode.ALL).call();
try {
    RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(git.getRepository());
    for(Ref branch : branches) {
        RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(branch.getObjectId());
        if(youngestCommit == null || commit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen().compareTo(
           youngestCommit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen()) > 0)
           youngestCommit = commit;
    }
} catch (...)
```

Comment: Would it return the youngest commit by date in the whole repo regardless of the branches?

Comment: No, it will return the commit to which `HEAD` points to (usually the current branch).

Comment: The snippet assumes that the newest commit is among the branch heads, which may, at least in theory, not be the case. Or am I missing something? Another issue is that the author timestamp is compared. Use `getCommiterIdent().getWhen()` instead.

Answer (score 13):

You could make use of `git log` and set it to only return the top most commit:

```java
RevCommit latestCommit = new Git(repository).
   log().
   setMaxCount(1).
   call().
   iterator().
   next();

String latestCommitHash = latestCommit.getName();
```

Answer (score 3):

Below you can find a **Java 8 Stream API** solution:

```
final List<Ref> branches = git.branchList().setListMode(ListBranchCommand.ListMode.ALL).call();
final RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(git.getRepository());

branches.stream()
        .map(branch -> {
            try {
                return revWalk.parseCommit(branch.getObjectId());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        })
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing((RevCommit commit) -> commit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen()).reversed())
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(commit -> {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s (%s)%n", commit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen(), commit.getShortMessage(), commit.getAuthorIdent().getName());
        });
```

It iterates over all branches and picks recent commits in those branches, then it sorts list of commits by date in descendant order and picks the first one. If it exists it prints to console output something like this:

```
Wed Aug 30 09:49:42 CEST 2017: test file added (Szymon Stepniak)
```

Of course the behavior on last commit existence is exemplary and it can be easily replaced with any additional business logic. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

To find the newest commit within a repository, configure a `RevWalk` to start from all known refs and sort it descending by commit date. For example:

```
Repository repo = ...
try( RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( repo ) ) {
  revWalk.sort( RevSort.COMMIT_TIME_DESC );
  Map<String, Ref> allRefs = repo.getRefDatabase().getRefs( RefDatabase.ALL );
  for( Ref ref : allRefs.values() ) {
    RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit( ref.getLeaf().getObjectId() );
    revWalk.markStart( commit );
  }
  RevCommit newestCommit = revWalk.next();
}
```

Depending on your use case, you may also want to mark start points from refs from `repo.getRefDatabase().getAdditionalRefs()` which includes refs like `FETCH_RESULT`, `ORIG_HEAD`, etc. If you find that there are still untracked refs, use `repo.getRefDatabase().getRef()`.

Comment: I don't get this. The loop over refs does nothing but overwrite the `RevWalk` starting point at each iteration. Why didn't you use the last ref instead?

Comment: `markStart` does not override but adds a starting point. After the `for` loop, the `RevWalk` is configured to sort commits by time and include commits from all refs returned by `getRefs(...)`