# Jgit Author last commit

Tags: groovy, jgit

I've found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820282/get-the-latest-commit-in-a-repository-with-jgit) and base on it, but I got error `Cannot invoke method getAuthorIdent() on null object`. I try to get last commit, check if it's equal to `badAuthor`. Why it cannot be `null`? And if statement will work like I want?

```
def authorEqual() {

def badAuthor = 'John'
Git git = Git.open(new File(".git"))  
RevCommit lastCommit = null --> ERROR FROM HERE
List<Ref> branches = new Git(git.repository).branchList().setListMode(ListMode.ALL).call();   
    try {
        RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(git.repository) 
        for(Ref branch : branches){
          RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(branch.getObjectId());  
          PersonIdent aAuthor = commit.getAuthorIdent()
          if(commit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen().compareTo(
        -----------^ <-- HERE ERROR
              lastCommit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen().equals(badAuthor)) > 0)

              lastCommit = commit;
              println commit
```

Comment: I think you haven't set lastCommit before using it.

Comment: `RevCommit lastCommit = null` --> Example from linked question

Comment: you should check if lastCommit is null. Anyway, if you wanted to find commits made by bad actor why do you need the last commit at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider Groovy way of finding last commit:

```
RevCommit lastCommit = branches.collect { branch -> revWalk.parseCommit(branch.objectId) }
        .sort { commit -> commit.authorIdent.when }
        .reverse()
        .first()
```

What it does it collects last commits from all branches, then it sorts them by date in descendant order and gets the most recent one. Having last commit you can easily check who was the author of it and execute any additional logic. Below you can find Groovy script example:

```
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.ListBranchCommand
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Ref
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk

@Grab(group='org.eclipse.jgit', module='org.eclipse.jgit', version='4.8.0.201706111038-r')

Git git = Git.open(new File("."))
List<Ref> branches = git.branchList().setListMode(ListBranchCommand.ListMode.ALL).call()
RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(git.repository)
String excludeAuthorsCommit = 'Joe Doe'

RevCommit lastCommit = branches.collect { branch -> revWalk.parseCommit(branch.objectId) }
        .sort { commit -> commit.authorIdent.when }
        .reverse()
        .first()

println "${lastCommit.authorIdent.when}: ${lastCommit.shortMessage} (${lastCommit.authorIdent.name})"

if (lastCommit.authorIdent.name == excludeAuthorsCommit) {
    // Do what you want
}
```

I've tested it in project with 5 branches. It returned recent commit from `test` branch I did couple minutes ago. I hope it helps.

Comment: Cool, that's it. Thanks ! In if statement  `git.rm()` will remove that last file from that author ?

Comment: No. `git.rm()` returns [`RmCommand`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.3.1.201302201838-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/RmCommand.html) instance only and you have to set file patterns you want to remove from repository. But you have `RevCommit` and you can get tree from it, walk over files and add them to `RmCommand`.

Comment: You have right, but I thnik the easiest way will be use `ResetCommand`

Answer (score 2):

You can write as follows to find the bad author.

```
def badAuthor = 'John'
Git git = Git.open(new File(".git"))  
List<Ref> branches = new Git(git.repository).branchList().setListMode(ListMode.ALL).call();   
    try {
        RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(git.repository) 
        for(Ref branch in branches){

          RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(branch.getObjectId());  

          PersonIdent aAuthor = commit.getAuthorIdent()

          if(commit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen.equals(badAuthor))    
              println commit
```

Comment: It check all commits ? I need to check the last one, then if it will be equals, delete it, it can be done ?

Comment: do you mean the last commit on every branch or the last commit on specific branch?

Comment: on every branch